# How to smoothen the graph to find all the local maximas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I want to find the local maximas of a given set of points.
For Ex. -

```
xpoints_ball = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,224,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298])
ypoints_ball = np.array([238,241,243,243,246,251,254,258,259,263,270,276,280,287,288,293,301,312,319,330,331,339,351,360,373,386,385,398,407,428,394,453,454,469,486,504,520,537,538,555,575,593,615,634,633,655,676,697,724,733,734,732,732,730,729,729,728,729,730,730,733,736,736,739,742,746,751,756,756,760,767,774,781,788,790,796,807,773,742,715,718,683,660,636,615,594,595,572,556,538,524,510,511,494,469,455,448,448,436,429,418,411,403,403,394,389,385,381,375,376,372,369,364,363,360,360,357,357,356,355,354,352,340,330,318,310,311,301,292,285,276,268,304,264,256,251,246,241,240,235,231,226,220,227,225,234,237,229,240,241,244,249,250,251,255,257,262,264,268,268,274,277,280,286,291,291,294,301,309,313,318,319,325,331,338,354,354,361,367,379,386,393,403,411,421,430,441,441,454,461,474,494,496,509,522,534,545,561,560,573,587,603,616,632,629,643,662,688,721,721,719,720,718,718,722,721,723,723,727,729,732,735,739,739,742,747,752,729,692,692,667,639,611,591,565,569,547,529,512,491,478,463,449,439,429,415,418,409,400,391,384,380,381,374,367,363,361,360,360,358,354,354,352,352,352,352,352,352,347,334,338])

plt.plot(xpoints_ball, ypoints_ball)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For smoothening the graph I used cubic interpolation -

```
f_ball = interp1d(xpoints_ball, ypoints_ball, kind='cubic' , fill_value="extrapolate")
plt.plot(xpoints_ball, f_ball(xpoints_ball))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, for finding the local maximas, i use the peak function of Scipy library -

```
coordinates = f_ball(xpoints_ball)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(coordinates)
plt.plot(coordinates)
plt.plot(peaks, coordinates[peaks], "x")
```

[image]

This result gives me a lot of false positive values which are not the local maximas.
How do I modify the above code so that the result of the local maximas is something like this -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can smooth your data using e.g. Gaussian filter and control it using sigma parameter

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

xpoints_ball = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,224,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298])
ypoints_ball = np.array([238,241,243,243,246,251,254,258,259,263,270,276,280,287,288,293,301,312,319,330,331,339,351,360,373,386,385,398,407,428,394,453,454,469,486,504,520,537,538,555,575,593,615,634,633,655,676,697,724,733,734,732,732,730,729,729,728,729,730,730,733,736,736,739,742,746,751,756,756,760,767,774,781,788,790,796,807,773,742,715,718,683,660,636,615,594,595,572,556,538,524,510,511,494,469,455,448,448,436,429,418,411,403,403,394,389,385,381,375,376,372,369,364,363,360,360,357,357,356,355,354,352,340,330,318,310,311,301,292,285,276,268,304,264,256,251,246,241,240,235,231,226,220,227,225,234,237,229,240,241,244,249,250,251,255,257,262,264,268,268,274,277,280,286,291,291,294,301,309,313,318,319,325,331,338,354,354,361,367,379,386,393,403,411,421,430,441,441,454,461,474,494,496,509,522,534,545,561,560,573,587,603,616,632,629,643,662,688,721,721,719,720,718,718,722,721,723,723,727,729,732,735,739,739,742,747,752,729,692,692,667,639,611,591,565,569,547,529,512,491,478,463,449,439,429,415,418,409,400,391,384,380,381,374,367,363,361,360,360,358,354,354,352,352,352,352,352,352,347,334,338])


ypoints_ball_smooth=gaussian_filter(ypoints_ball, sigma=0.8)

plt.plot(xpoints_ball, ypoints_ball)
plt.plot(xpoints_ball, ypoints_ball_smooth,"--")

peaks, _ = find_peaks(ypoints_ball_smooth)
plot(xpoints_ball[peaks],ypoints_ball_smooth[peaks],"ro")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
import numpy as np

def smooth(array, window_len=10, window="hanning"):
    """np.array, int, str => np.array
    Smooth the data using a window with requested size.
    
    This method is based on the convolution of a scaled window with the signal.
    The signal is prepared by introducing reflected copies of the signal 
    (with the window size) at both ends so that transient parts are minimized
    in the beginning and end part of the output signal.
    
    input:
        x: the input signal 
        window_len: the dimension of the smoothing window; should be an odd integer
        window: the type of window from 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman'
            flat window will produce a moving average smoothing.
    output:
        the smoothed signal
        
    example:
        t = linspace(-2,2,0.1)
        x = sin(t)+randn(len(t))*0.1
        y = smooth(x)
    
    see also: 
    
    numpy.hanning, numpy.hamming, numpy.bartlett, numpy.blackman, numpy.convolve
    scipy.signal.lfilter
    """

    if array.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError("smooth only accepts 1 dimension arrays.")

    if array.size < window_len:
        raise ValueError("Input vector needs to be bigger than window size.")

    if window_len < 3:
        return x

    if not window in ["flat", "hanning", "hamming", "bartlett", "blackman"]:
        raise ValueError(
            "Window must be one of 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman'"
        )

    s = np.r_[array[window_len - 1 : 0 : -1], array, array[-2 : -window_len - 1 : -1]]
    
    if window == "flat":  # moving average
        w = np.ones(window_len, "d")
    else:
        w = eval("np." + window + "(window_len)")

    y = np.convolve(w / w.sum(), s, mode="valid")

    y = y[int(window_len / 2 - 1) : -int(window_len / 2)]
    offset = len(y) - len(array)  # in case input and output are not of the same lenght
    assert len(array) == len(y[offset:])
    return y[offset:]
```